# How to redirect, using .htaccess, multiple top level domains to one top level domain without www?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, no-www

I have multiple domains with different TLDs (.com, .net, .org) but what's in front of the TLD is the same.

I would like to redirect the .net and .org to .com, without www:

1. `www.<domain>.net`, `<domain>.net`
2. `www.<domain>.org`, `<domain>.org`
3. `www.<domain>.com`

to be redirected to:

- `<domain>.com` (without www)

`<domain>` is dynamic and I don't want to hard-code it in .htaccess.

For redirecting www to non-www I use the following condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I would like to extend this condition to include also the TLD condition and to achieve the 301 redirect **in one step**. I want to avoid two redirects as in:

```
www.<domain>.net -[301]-> <domain>.net -[301]-> <domain>.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the idea posted by [Croises](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4175750/croises), this is what I end up with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)\.(?:net|org)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)\.(?:com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)\.(?:com|net|org)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^%1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. non .com get redirected to .com but .com ends up redirecting to itself. Too many redirects.

Comment: Did you clear your cache or try with other browser ?

Comment: Yes, I tried with multiple browsers, cleared cache and also used curl

I have this domain: santestlaborator.ro, santestlaborator.com (I changed the RewriteCond to include .ro)

Using `curl -I http://www.santestlaborator.com` I get 301 but the same thing i get for `curl -I http://santestlaborator.com`

Comment: The `%1` from the 2nd RewriteCond line doesn't bind to the `(.+)` group from the first RewriteCond.
So when `HTTP_HOST` is `<domain>.com`, the second RewriteCond is true because `<domain>.com` is different than evaluated `.com`.

It works when i hard code the domain in the 2nd RewriteCond, instead of `%1`